# Select statement does not pull all the data from a field - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, coldfusion-9

I have this query to get results out of my database. My problem is that the `selectedanswer` part of the select statement does not pull all of the data from `r.textboxmulti`.

Below is my query.

```
     <cfquery name="fullResults" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
    select s.id, s.name surveyname, q.question, subq.answer subquestion, isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(a.answer, **r.textboxmulti**),r.other),r.textbox),r.truefalse) as **selectedanswer**, a.*, r.*
    from results r
    join questions q on r.questionidfk = q.id
    left join answers subq on r.itemidfk = subq.id
    left join answers a on r.answeridfk = a.id
    join surveys s on q.surveyidfk = s.id
    where owneridfk = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.ownerid#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="35">
    order by s.id, owneridfk, q.rank, subq.rank desc
   </cfquery
```

Comment: What is the data type of `textboxmulti`? If it is `text` consider changing it to a data type that is not deprecated (e.g. `varchar(max)` if you truly need > 8K).

Comment: the data type is not the issue here because if i run something like SELECT textboxmulti FROM results I am able to get all of the results back.

Comment: Then can you better describe what "not pull all of the data" means? At what point is it truncating, 255, 4000, 8000 characters, something else? What happens if you run the query somewhere other than Cold Fusion?

Comment: I would say it cuts off at about 255. I ran the query on SQL Management Studio and I have a column 'selectedanswer' which displays the results trancated and another column 'textboxmulti' next to it which displays all of the data and is type varchar(max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you explain what you mean by "all the data"?  If you mean that it is not pulling data from r.textboxmulti for some rows, that mean that it is null for those rows and that fact is being masked by by the isnulls you have it wrapped in (incidentally, you could consider using a coalesce instead of nesting isnull....)

If you mean that it is getting data but leaving some of it off then one possibility is that it is being truncated.  This can happen if SQL Server (or the next stage of processing where you are veiwing it...) sees it as a data type that is too small to hold the return value, this can sometimes happen due to implicit type conversions.  You can deal with that by explicitly casting towards a large enough data type.

A final, rare, possibility is that r.textboxmulti containst an ascii null character.  Many programs (including the SQL Server print command...) take that as a command to stop displaying anything from that string afterwards.  This does not come up often, but I have encountered it myself.

Comment: It is getting some of the data out and the rest is truncated. I believe the second of your options is my issue.

Comment: That makes sense.  Remember that isnull is trying to return the datatype of the first value entered.  So if say a.answer is varchar(10) and r.textboxmulti is varchar(20) you could have problems and a forced cast could help.

Comment: @Crematorio can you tell us which part of this solution led to a resolution of the problem?

Comment: Well, @TimothyAWiseman's options above led me into checking each table data types and their character limitations. The a.answer had a limit of 255 characters. Then I used the convert part from your solution and I am converting the a.answer to varchar(max). The reason for giving Timothy the answer credit is because he found my issue first and also provided a more detailed response to my question

Answer (score 2):

Try using `COALESCE` instead of `ISNULL`. These lead to different data type precedence rules - I suspect `a.answer` is `varchar(255)`. Also can't hurt to explicitly convert the first argument:

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), a.answer),
  r.textboxmulti, r.other, r.textbox, r.truefalse)
```

Comment: I believe this fixed my issue. I only used the convert part though because everything else was giving me an error

Comment: Coalesce can except more than two arguments, there would be no need to next coalesce like that.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server management studio there is a setting that tells it how many characters to show for a column in the grid, or in text view.

If you're going to use the data in an application; are you seing all the data there? That is a sure sign that you use the default setting in SSMS to show only 255 characters.